# mysql - limit left join

Tags: mysql, sql

left say for instance that I have the following query and want to limit the `left join` on a table, how do I achieve that?

```
SELECT * FROM Base
LEFT JOIN Derived1 ON Base.id = Derived1.id
LEFT JOIN Derived2 ON Base.id = Derived2.id
LEFT JOIN Derived3 ON (Base.id = Derived3.id WHERE Derived3.name LIKE 'test%' LIMIT 5) <-----
WHERE Base.id = 'someid';
```

---

I though I could write it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Base
LEFT JOIN Derived1 ON Base.id = Derived1.id
LEFT JOIN Derived2 ON Base.id = Derived2.id
LEFT JOIN Derived3 ON Base.id = (
    SELECT d3.id FROM Derived3 d3
    WHERE d3.name LIKE 'test%' AND Base.id = Derived3.id
    LIMIT 5
)
WHERE Base.id = 'someid';
```

but this gives me the incorrect result

I want all data which is inside `Derived3` but only 5 items if Derived.name equals to `test 1`, `test 2`, `test 3` etc.
There might be 100 000 000 tests inside that tables and a couple of thousand other stuff which doesn't start with `'test'`.

So basically, give me anything inside `Derived3` and max 5 rows that start with `'test'`.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Any time you have enumerated tables or columns, alarm bells should start ringing.

Comment: The alarm bells rang and is now broken, I really need to fix without changing the structure since we have billions of records and this is a somewhat huge project. So I need to come up with a nice query even though it might not be the most efficient way of solving this problem.

Comment: Select ur Baseid from Derived3 keeping all your join and join conditions intactand see if that works @Dr.Jones

Answer (score 0):

Check the bellow query.

```
SELECT *
FROM Base
LEFT JOIN Derived1 ON Base.id = Derived1.id
LEFT JOIN Derived2 ON Base.id = Derived2.id
LEFT JOIN Derived3 ON (
        Base.id = Derived3.id
        AND Derived3.id IN (
            SELECT Derived3.id
            FROM Derived3
            WHERE Derived3.NAME LIKE 'test%' LIMIT 5
            )
        )
WHERE Base.id = 'someid'
```

Comment: I can't run limit inside IN/ANY since its not supported =/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can fit in your scenario but you can select from Derived3 using filter `LIKE 'test%'` and join the select result using alias.

I don't have MySql installed to try this but something like this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM Base
LEFT JOIN Derived1 ON Base.id = Derived1.id
LEFT JOIN Derived2 ON Base.id = Derived2.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT d3.id FROM Derived3 d3
    WHERE d3.name LIKE 'test%'
    LIMIT 5
) Derived3Alias ON Base.id = Derived3Alias.id
WHERE Base.id = 'someid'
GROUP BY Base.id;
```

Maybe you will need to write "as Derived3Alias" but try first without 'as' I think it should work.

Comment: I can't even run describe on this because it takes forever... Is this really correct?

Comment: Sorry, previous link is wrong (I deleted the comment).. This is the correct one http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f17b7c/9

Comment: If you open last link I also added group by test1.id (Base.id in your case).. I'm not sure do you need it or not